# Control Size increases on Korean OS

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, globalization

I have a windows Form that has a Label control specified with fixed size. It's Autosize value is true and the maximum size contains the same value for width as the width of the control, so that, the control only increases it's height if the need be. This works fine on English OS, but when this is deployed on say Korean OS, the width increases and crosses the maximum limit set in the form.

I have played with Autoscalemode with all the values - Font, DPI, None, Inherit, but doesn't change a thing. What could be wrong with it and How can we overcome this problem.

Comment: Aren't the character heights higher in Korean than they are in English? Do you intend for the tops of characters to be cut off? That's going to make things difficult to read...

Comment: This is not actually about the Font size as that is still taken automatically. But the size and maximum size property contain different values when deployed in Korean. For example, I have a control of size 548, 200, the maximum width set is 548. But this gets changed to 639 in Korean OS. My understanding was that MaximumSize, MinimumSize properties are read only. So, my question is why is it behaving this way.

Comment: Just to be more clear - I have set MaximumSize Value as - (548, 200). This gets converted to (639,185)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it increases and actually is well known (in some circles) behavior. There is some problem with how font are measured (probably fallback font is measured instead of the one you defined).

Instead of setting the size to fixed, I would use TableLayoutPanel as layout manager for this control/form/whatever and allow it to actually resize. You'll need to play with it a bit, but from my experience adding empty distance column works (provided that you have at least one percentage column). This is a bit tricky, but I managed to fix similar defect this way.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had this same issue, and fixed it by programmatically setting the default font to Sans Serif in the main top-level panel. Details of my answer (to my own question) here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1093919/is-there-such-a-thing-as-korean-microsoft-windows-10-or-is-it-just-regular-win/1119806#1119806